# Geometry proof involving triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be an acute angle triangle with $\angle B>\angle C$. Let
$M$ be mid point of $BC$. Points $E$,$F$ are feet of altitudes from $B$ and $C$. Points $K$,$L$ are mid points of segments $ME$ and $MF$. let $T$ be point of $KL$ such that $TA$ is parallel to $BC$.

Prove that $TA=TM$.

I have tried to solve it but was unable to even start it. Ding by coordinate geometry is too messy. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It basically suffices to prove that $\overline{AM}$ is the angle bisector of $\angle{TMB}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Few elementary things:

- Quadrilaterals $EHFA$ and $BCFE$ are cyclic.
- $MB=ME=MF=MC$

First we have to prove an important fact:

> Segments $ME,MF,TA$ are tangent to circle $EHFA$

Let's prove it for segment $MF$. We'll use the fact that the angle between the tangent and the chord must be equal to the inscribed angle constructed above the same chord. In other words, if $MF$ is tangent to the circle $EHFA$ then:

$$\angle MFE=\angle FAE=\alpha\tag{1}$$

We can easily prove that (1) is true:

$$\angle MFE=\angle BFE+\angle MFB=\angle BCE+\angle MBF=(90^\circ-\beta)+(90^\circ-\gamma)=(180^\circ-\beta-\gamma)=\alpha$$

You can prove that $ME$ and $TA$ are tangent to circle $EHFA$ in exactly the same way.

Back to the original problem.

Consider two circles:

- The first one is circle $EHFA$
- The second one is circle with center $M$ and radius equal to zero (yes, it sounds funny but circles with zero radius are actually quite useful in geometry).

Segements $ME$ and $MF$ are tangent to both circles. Radical axis of these two circles has to pass through midpoints of both common tangents. In other words, line $KL$ represents radical axis of the two circles and the point $T$ is on the radical axis.

Consequentially, the point T has the same power with respect to both circles:

$$Pow_{EHFA}(T)=Pow_M(T)$$

$$TA^2=TM^2$$

$$TA=TM$$

Comment: Just a minor doubt... Can we really use the fact that point M is a circle of radius 0 ? I have read online , that many theorems relating to circles ( and tangents) do not apply to circles of 0 radius .

Comment: @RahulRamachandran Yes, you are allowed to consider and use circles of zero radius. Imagine a circle with a tangent line. If you start reducing the circle radius, the tangent remains well defined, no matter how small the radius becomes. Eventually, the radius becomes infinitely small but the tangent and the circle center are still there.